# select2 height change with theme: classic not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

When I tried to change the height of the `select2` dropdown the arrow dropdown height doesn't change so it looks weird the text also looks weird. How do I make the height of the arrow dropdown match the select height.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="platform">Platform</option>
</select>
var select2 = $("select").select2({
theme: "classic",
});
select2.data('select2').$selection.css('height', '100px');
```

EDIT: I figure it out for the arrow, but text still looks weird.

```
.select2-selection__arrow {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use three classes:

`select2-selection__arrow` is for arrow

`select2-container .select2-selection--single` is for selection container

`select2-selection__rendered` is for rendered text

If you want to change only some of your select box you can add custom class to `$container` like this: `$($('#cars').data('select2').$container).addClass('carclass')` then use the class to change height.

```js
 $("select").select2({
            theme: "classic",
        });

$($('#cars').data('select2').$container).addClass('carclass')
```

```css
.carclass .select2-selection__rendered {
            line-height: 100px !important;
        }

   .carclass.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
            height: 100px !important;
        }

     .carclass .select2-selection__arrow {
            height: 100px !important;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 
 <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="platform">Platform</option>
    </select>
    
     <select name="cars1" id="cars1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="platform">Platform</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: is there a class to change the select2 height? My code only works for 1 select 2 but I have like 10, and i dont want to hardcode it for all 10

Comment: The three class are general for all select2 drop downs and changes any drop downs height that you have. you can test it for two drop downs and still working for both of them

Comment: thanks. question what happens if I only wanted to do it for only 1 select2 index? How do i only target that 1 and not all?

Comment: You can use `$($('#cars').data('select2').$container).addClass('carclass')` to add custom class. I updated my answer

Comment: Honestly thanks so much for the help. I feel bad for bother you so much haha. One last thing (if you don't have time no worries). How would you change it so that #cars is actually a class .car (so height changes for 2 select2 but not 3 select2)

Comment: You want to have 3 selectbox so that two of them change height and the last one does not change?

Comment: yes and of those 3 selectbox. Two of them has the class name .cars I tried $($('.cars').data('select2').$container).addClass('carclass'); but it only worked for 1. Again if you're buys don't worry about it I already bother you a lot. I'll figure it out haha

Comment: Yes your right that is because of `data('select2')` that only select first select box,. Use Id instead: `$('#cars1').data('select2').$container.addClass('carclass');  $('#cars2').data('select2').$container.addClass('carclass'); `